# Autofac: organising component registration logically

Tags: autofac

In an asp.net MVC application, rather than bloating Application_Start() with lots of Autofac scaffolding such as Component registrations, I wish to organise the application by having this is separate files.

Is there an example of a pattern I could follow for this? Is this what an autofac module is for?

For example, if i wanted all of the Widget-related registration in the same file, maybe in the Widget MVC area somewhere:

```
builder.RegisterType<FooWidget>().As<IWidget>();
builder.RegisterType<BarWidget>().As<IWidget>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That is exactly what modules do. Depending on how much you need to register, you could choose to create a module per assembly, module per concept/type (i.e. `ControllersModule`, `RepositoriesModule` etc). In your case you might want to have a `WidgetsModule`. Your `Application_Start()` will then be nothing more than:

```
Assembly[] assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().OfType<Assembly>().ToArray();

var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies);
IContainer container = containerBuilder.Build();
```

There are a lot of useful methods for registering types. It might minimize the amount of registration code to a point where it is fine to have it in a single place. In your example a `RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).As<IWidget>()` should be enough to register all `IWidget`s.

If I know I'm going to require a lot of registrations, I start with modules. Other times I start small and put all registrations in one place until the need arises for more readable/maintainable solution and then refactor towards modules.